# actualizacion APK fuera del Google play, error : android.os.FileUriExposedException:

Tags: android, apk, update

Tengo problemas con la actualización del *apk*; lo que he tratado de hacer 1° descarga la información de un *txt* alojado en dropbox y comparo los datos de versión. Si hay actualización debería bajar el archivo. El problema que me reporta el log es:

```
2018-10-29 16:36:38.491 2600-2641/santabeatriz.ventas4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: santabeatriz.ventas4, PID: 2600
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/download/app.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8933)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8894)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
        at santabeatriz.ventas4.Autoupdater$2.doInBackground(Autoupdater.java:299)
        at santabeatriz.ventas4.Autoupdater$2.doInBackground(Autoupdater.java:262)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Mi código es:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    EditText edtuserid,edtpass;
    Button btnlogin;
    ProgressBar pbbar;
    private DBHelper helper;
    private int ide;
    public final static String Valor1 = "";

    private Autoupdater updater;
    private RelativeLayout loadingPanel;
    private Context context;

    private static final int CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION = 332;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_ALL = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}; //TODO You can Add multiple permissions here.
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 223;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            loadingPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel);
            //Esto sirve si la actualizacion no se realiza al principio. No es este caso.
            //loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            comenzarActualizar();

        }catch (Exception ex){
            //Por Cualquier error.
            Toast.makeText(this,ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }


        helper = new DBHelper(this);
        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        edtuserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtuserid);
        edtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpass);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        pbbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
        pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //obtener el usuario guardado
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edtuserid.setText(preferences.getString("usuario", ""));
         if (edtuserid.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

        }else{
             edtpass.requestFocus();
         }

        edtpass.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    // Perform action on key press
                    //Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    DoLogin doLogin = new DoLogin();
                    doLogin.execute("");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DoLogin doLogin = new DoLogin();
                doLogin.execute("");
            }

        });
    }

    private void comenzarActualizar(){

        context = this;

        updater = new Autoupdater(this);

        loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        updater.DownloadData(finishBackgroundDownload);
    }

    private Runnable finishBackgroundDownload = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if(updater.isNewVersionAvailable()){


                String msj = "Nueva Version: " + updater.isNewVersionAvailable();
                msj += "\nCurrent Version: " + updater.getCurrentVersionName() + "(" + updater.getCurrentVersionCode() + ")";
                msj += "\nLastest Version: " + updater.getLatestVersionName() + "(" + updater.getLatestVersionCode() +")";
                msj += "\nDesea Actualizar?";
                //Crea ventana de alerta.
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dialog1.setMessage(msj);
                dialog1.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
                //Establece el boton de Aceptar y que hacer si se selecciona.
                dialog1.setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //Vuelve a poner el ProgressBar mientras se baja e instala.
                        loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //Se ejecuta el Autoupdater con la orden de instalar. Se puede poner un listener o no

                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                            } else {

                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                            }
                        }


                    }
                });

                dialog1.show();

            }else{

                Log.d("No Hay actualizaciones", "error");
            }
        }
    };



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    updater.InstallNewVersion(null);
                } else {

                    Log.e("Update", "Permiso denegado");
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

}

public class Autoupdater {

    Context context;

    Runnable listener;

    private static final String INFO_FILE ="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/xxx/version.txt"; 
    private int currentVersionCode;

    private String currentVersionName;

    private int latestVersionCode;

    private String latestVersionName;

    private String downloadURL;

    public Autoupdater(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private void getData() {
        try{
            // Datos locales
            Log.d("AutoUpdater", "GetData");
            PackageInfo pckginfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            currentVersionCode = pckginfo.versionCode;
            currentVersionName = pckginfo.versionName;

            // Datos remotos
            String data = downloadHttp(new URL(INFO_FILE));
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
            latestVersionCode = json.getInt("versionCode");
            latestVersionName = json.getString("versionName");
            downloadURL = json.getString("downloadURL");
            Log.d("AutoUpdate", "Datos obtenidos con éxito");
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("AutoUpdate", "Ha habido un error con el JSON", e);
        }catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
            Log.e("AutoUpdate", "Ha habido un error con el packete :S", e);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e("AutoUpdate", "Ha habido un error con la descarga", e);
        }
    }

    public boolean isNewVersionAvailable() {
        return getLatestVersionCode() > getCurrentVersionCode();
    }

    public int getCurrentVersionCode() {
        return currentVersionCode;
    }

    public String getCurrentVersionName() {
        return currentVersionName;
    }

    public int getLatestVersionCode() {
        return latestVersionCode;
    }

    public String getLatestVersionName() {
        return latestVersionName;
    }

    public String getDownloadURL() {
        return downloadURL;
    }

    private static String downloadHttp(URL url) throws IOException {
        // Codigo de coneccion, Irrelevante al tema.
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setReadTimeout(15 * 1000);
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.connect();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public void DownloadData(Runnable OnFinishRunnable){
        //Guarda el listener.
        this.listener = OnFinishRunnable;
        //Ejecuta el AsyncTask para bajar los datos.
        Log.e("Update error!", "Comienza Descarga APK");
        downloaderData.execute();
    }

    public void InstallNewVersion(Runnable OnFinishRunnable){

        if(isNewVersionAvailable()){
            if(getDownloadURL() == "") return;
            listener = OnFinishRunnable;
            String params[] = {getDownloadURL()};
            downloadInstaller.execute(params);

        }
    }

    private AsyncTask downloaderData = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            //llama al metodo auxiliar que seteara todas las variables.
            getData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);

            if(listener != null)listener.run();
            listener = null;
        }
    };

    private AsyncTask<String, Integer, Intent> downloadInstaller = new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Intent>() {
        @Override
        protected Intent doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();

                String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                // File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();//till here, it works fine - .apk is download to my sdcard in download file


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.e("Update error!", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Intent intent) {
            super.onPostExecute(intent);
            if(listener != null)listener.run();
            listener = null;
        }
    };
}
```

El error sale en el public Autoupdate >>> `context.startActivity(intent);`. 
La comprobación de versión del archivo *apk*, funciona bien.. si me pueden guiar en que estoy mal se los agradecería

Comment: Un saludo @Carlosd, te invito a leer como incluir un [mcve]. Seguir esa recomendación a la hora de escribir una pregunta mejorará tus probabilidades de obtener ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el  `targetSdkVersion` de tu app?

Comment: el targetSdkVersion: 24, con minSdk: 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error [FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html) es generado a partir de [Android N](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) (Android 7.0)m esto si estas haciendo uso del metodo `Uri.fromFile()`, en este caso lo estas realizando en esta linea:

```
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

Para solucionar este problema, debes validar si estas usando un sistema operativo mayor o igual a Android 7.0 y usar el método `Uri.parse()` en lugar de `Uri.fromFile()`:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
  } else{
      intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si analizas el mensaje del log indica que la *causa* del error es que tu aplicación está lanzando la excepción **`android.os.FileUriExposedException`**.

Esto se debe a que tu `targetSdkVersion >= 24`. En ese caso, debes utilizar una clase `FileProvider` para dar acceso a un archivo o carpeta a otras aplicaciones. Para ello, lo mejor es crear tu propia clase que herede de `FileProvider`, de manera que se asegure que nuestro *FileProvider* no entre en conflicto con otros *FileProviders* declarados en los imports, más información [aquí](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/06/27/fileprovider-libraries.html) (en inglés).

Los pasos para reemplazar la *URI* `file://` con una URI `content://` son:

- Agregar una clase que extienda `FileProvider`

  ```
  public class GenericFileProvider extends FileProvider {}
  ```
- Agregar un tag `<provider>` en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` bajo el tag `<application>`. Especificar una autoridad única para el atributo `android:authorities` para evitar conflictos, las dependencias importadas deben especificar `${applicationId}.provider` y otras autoridades de uso común.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    <application
        ...
        <provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.my.package.name.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

- Crear un archivo `provider_paths.xml` en la carpeta `res/xml`. (Si no existe la carpeta, debe crearse). El contenido de este archivo se muestra a continuación. Este describe que queremos compartir el acceso a la carpeta raíz del almacenamiento externo `(path=".")` con el nombre **external_files**.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

- Luego debes cambiar la línea de código donde construyes el *URI* del archivo, a una que obtenga el *URI* utilizando el FileProvider, en tu caso sería cambiar esto:

  ```
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
  ```

  a algo como esto:

  ```
  intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,  context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".my.package.name.provider", new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
  ```
- Si utilizas un intent para hacer que el sistema abra el archivo, también debes agregar la siguiente linea de código :

  ```
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  ```

Más información y la explicación completa detrás de esta solución en [file:// scheme is now not allowed to be attached with Intent on targetSdkVersion 24 (Android Nougat). And here is the solution](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) (en Inglés).

Con información de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/255257) de StackOverflow en Inglés.

**EDICIÓN**: Para la funcionalidad *default* no es necesario escribir una clase que extienda `FileProvider`, se puede utilizar directamente la clase [`android.support.v4.content.FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider). Para más información leer la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) de dicha clase.

Comment: aplique lo que me indicas y ahora me sale el siguiente error W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: opening provider santabeatriz.ventas4.GenericFileProvider from ProcessRecord{7312bd2 13661:com.google.android.packageinstaller/u0a38} (pid=13661, uid=10038) that is not exported from UID 10136
2018-10-29 23:28:25.814 13661-17067/? W/InstallStaging: Error staging apk from content URI
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider santabeatriz.ventas4.GenericFileProvider from ProcessRecord{7312bd2 13661:com.google.android.packageinstaller/u0a38} (pid=13661, uid=10038)

Comment: Cambia `android:exported="false"` por `android:exported="true"` en el tag `<provider`. Por lo visto, el intent de instalación requiere que el provider esté exportado.

Comment: No me deja ahora abrir la app, sale: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: santabeatriz.ventas4, PID: 17734
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider santabeatriz.ventas4.GenericFileProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must not be exported

Comment: Vamos un paso atrás, según estoy viendo ahora, no puede exportarse un `FileProvider`(cosa que ignoraba, lo lamento) ¿Estás agregando la línea con el permiso?: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`

Comment: Según veo en [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090667/how-can-make-a-fileprovider-available-to-other-applications), es probable que eso es lo que te está haciendo falta.

Comment: Si habia agregado el permiso , lo que hice y me funciono es sacar una linea que es intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); en mi codigo y funciono. muchas gracias por la ayuda